# Docker Compose and Github Actions (docker-compose down isn't reached)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions

I created a `docker-compose.yml` file to build an environment to run test specs. I want to have these specs run when I push to Github using Github actions. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:  
  mongo:     
    image: mongo:3.4
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always    
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.8    
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    restart: always        
  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=dockerTest
    platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    depends_on:
      - redis     
    environment:
      - PORT=9000
      - NODE_ENV=dockerTest
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379            
    command: ['npm', 'run', 'test-docker']
```

When I run docker-compose locally, this works great!

I am trying to get it to run in github actions, here is my `workflows` file

```
name: Run Test Suite
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  run-tests-docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps: 
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build Docker Containers
      run:  docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build
   
    - name: Stop Containers
      if: always()
      run: docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" down
```

Since I run the command: `['npm', 'run', 'test-docker']`  in my webapp, it runs and executes my test specs. However, when it completes, mongodb and redis-server are still running in my docker container, so I never "exit" the process to get to the next step to stop the containers.

How can I proceed to the next the step after my test specs are done running and my webapp exits?

Currently, my webapp exits with code 0, but then github actions stays on the "Build Docker Containers" step since mongo and redis are running.

Comment: Please share your logs. You're running `docker-compose` with `-d` flag so it should return right away. You might need some sleep to let it complete before moving on to next step i.e. down. Your logs might be helpful to understand this better.